# NameError: name 'BillingView' is not defined

Tags: django

This is my url:

```
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', BillingView.as_view(), name="index"),

)
```

and this is the method in my `views.py`:

```
class BillingView(BaseCompositeView):

    """
    A view that lets you record new billing information. This view includes all
    of the forms needed by the users on one page.
    """
    # We cannot easily override FormView since this view uses multiple forms

    template_name = "billing/base_billing.html"
```

etc.

Why is my view is not accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using django 1.4? What is the name of the project?

You probably want this for your import:

```
from project.billing.views import *
```

`NameError` means you're referencing something that hasn't been defined or declared in the current scope.

Edit:

To help diagnose the issue, try this:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.2.3'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['/list/of/paths', '/and/other/paths/']
```

And just examine if the correct libraries are on your path. You might find that you've got a newer version of django in your site-libs folder amongst other things.

When are you getting the NameError? When running from the development server, or a production web server? Please show us the full error and stack trace.

Comment: I am using django 1.1.1 and my urls.py and views.py are in a same billing app

Comment: That seems **very** unlikely. Those class-based generic views weren't introduced until Django 1.3.

Comment: I am deploying a project and those class-based generic views were used in Django 1.1.1

Comment: @ChZeeshan unless you backported class based views, I also find it difficult to believe. Is there any other information you can share that may help us help you?